# Apache POI - Lock rows AND hidden sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have to create an Excel file with 3 sheets. Two of them should be hidden and locked, the other one no.

I have locked the two sheets in the following way:

```
XSSFSheet s = ((XSSFSheet)sheet);
s.lockDeleteColumns(true);
s.lockDeleteRows(true);
s.lockInsertColumns(true);
s.lockInsertRows(true);
s.lockObjects(true);
s.enableLocking();
```

and then I hide them

```
wb.setSheetHidden(0, true);
wb.setSheetHidden(2, true);
```

In this way when I open the Excel file only the sheet 1 will be visible. But then if I try to write something it appears a popup and says that the sheet is read-only. Instead if I make the sheet 0 not hidden, then the sheet 1 is writable.

In sheet 0 there are the dropdown values that are needed in sheet 1.

Is it possible to have sheet 0 hidden and still sheet 1 writable?

Thanks a lot

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121676/why-excel-treating-cells-as-protected-even-if-they-are-not/41126648#41126648. A `Excel` sheet can be in the selected sheets group even if it is not active and even it is hidden. So you need to `.setSelected(false)` all sheets which not shall be selected.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!!!!!!